# What is the best way to implement Socket.io in android?

Tags: android, socket.io

I am finding best way to implement socketio in android

Answer (score 0):

I implemented [this client](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java/blob/master/README.md) and everything will be working just fine.

Comment: My question is that can we create braodcast receiver so that it listen the emit done by sserver. If it is possbile then i will not have to create listener in SERVICE class

Comment: I think [this is](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/socket.io/socket.io_broadcasting.htm) what you're looking for.